# pass arg to function when using es6 bind with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can pass my args like this if I have props coming from another component if I use es6 arrow function in JSX.

```
class MyComponent extends Component({
  myFunc(param){
    console.log(param);
  }
   render(
    return(
      <button onClick="(param)=>myFunc(param)"></button>
    )
  )
})
```

But what if I you use this kind

```
class MyComponent extends Component({
  constructor(){
    this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this);
  }
  myFunc(){

  }
   render(
    return(
      <button onClick={this.myFunc}></button>
    )
  )
})
```

How can I pass the params?

Comment: for what purpose do you want to use this? is it for something like deleting a child object?

Comment: @illusionist I might want to pass something down to the children component.

Comment: `onClick={this.myFunc.bind(this)}` or `onClick={e => this.myFunc(e)}`

Comment: u can use it like this:  `<button onClick={this.myFunc.bind(this,param1,param2,param3)}></button>`  
`myFunc(param1,param2,param3){console.log(param1,param2,param3)}` 
dont bind it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have made the mistake in this line

```
constructor(){
  this.myFunc = myFunc.bind(this);
}
```

This should works:

```
constructor(){
  this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this);
}

myFunc(props){
  console.log(props);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass directly like the first one. But you can access in different way using `e.target`. But I am not sure on what scenario you want like this.

```
class MyComponent extends Component({
   constructor(){
       this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this);
   }
   myFunc(e){
     console.log(e.target.arg);
   }
   render(){
      return(
         <button arg={yourargument} onClick={this.myFunc}></button>
      )
  }
})
```